# What does out.absolute.dir meaning in linux?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ant

nI see in build files of different project in Linux frequently use of "out.absolute.dir" and I'm really curious about what does it exactly mean.So I write a short build file which I mentioned in following lines

```
<project name="Test_Ant_APK" default="print">
  <property name="cal.out.dir" location="${out.absolute.dir}"/> 
  <target name="print">
  <echo>p=${cal.out.dir}</echo>
  </target>
</project>
```

And when I run this build file from command line I got this output

Buildfile: /home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK/build.xml

print:

```
 [echo] p=/home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK/${out.absolute.dir}
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0 seconds

I little confused about output.I think we should have p=/home/jody/workspace/Test_Ant_APK as output. Why we have ${out.absolute.dir}
at the end of output? what does it mean? Does this build file have problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your buildscript.
You adress a propertyvalue with syntax `${...}`, but as the
property `out.absolute.dir` is not set within the project scope of your ant file it's getting echoed as is => `${out.absolute.dir}` which is normal for properties not set - in your case its added to the dir your ant script resides, because of the use of location attribute in property task.
See the difference when using property task with value attribute instead :

```
<project name="foo">    
  <property name="cal.out.dir" value="${out.absolute.dir}"/> 
  <target name="print">
  <echo>${cal.out.dir}</echo>
  </target>
</project>
```

output :

```
[echo] ${out.absolute.dir}
```

I believe the propertyname `$[out.absolute.dir}` might be taken in several scripts due to the fact that property task with attribute location means (taken from ant manual) :

> Sets the property to the absolute filename of the given file. If the
>   value of this attribute is an absolute path, it is left unchanged
>   (with / and \ characters converted to the current platforms
>   conventions). Otherwise it is taken as a path relative to the
>   project's basedir and expanded.

see ant [manual property task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) for details.
If you want the value of project name attribute to be echoed, you must use the builtin property `${ant.project.name}`, f.e :

```
<project name="foo">
 <echo>$${ant.project.name} => ${ant.project.name}</echo>   
</project>
```

see all builtin properties with :

```
<project>
 <echo>ant builtin properties:</echo>   
 <echoproperties prefix="ant"/>
 <echo>java builtin properties:</echo>
 <echoproperties prefix="java"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. It's really clear and complete answer. :)

Comment: @jodyabbot you're welcome :-) Added more details referring to the difference of using value or location attribute in property task. Also it's not OS specific, same behaviour on windows or linux.